# Why box-sizing:border-box has no effect on img?

Tags: html, css, image

My photo has `370px*370px` by default. And I want my border, padding were included in these dimensions.
I try to achieve this effect with `box-sizing: border-box`. But I can't. Why?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



img {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rp2vtv6m/Layer-6-1.png" alt="">
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}



img#origin {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
}

.img-wrapper{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 370px;
  height: 370px;
}

.img-wrapper > img{
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Yours</h2>
<img id="origin" src="https://i.postimg.cc/rp2vtv6m/Layer-6-1.png" alt="">


<h2> If you want to make a box 370x370, wrap the img using div</h2>
<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rp2vtv6m/Layer-6-1.png" alt="">
</div>
```